# Animation from top to bottom in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-animations

I make my project in Bootstrap 4.

I have this code:

```
.back-to-top {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #c1c1c1;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 15px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

.back-to-top::before {
    padding-top: 15px;
    animation-name: animation-arrow;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes animation-arrow {
    0% {
        padding-top: 0px
    }
    50% {
        padding-top: 5px
    }
    100% {
        padding-top: 10px
    }
}


<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="back-to-top" role="button"><img src="images/back.png" class="img-fluid"> </a>
```

I'd like to move the images / back.png up / down arrow.

(I would like the picture to move slightly up / down) - but it doesn't work

How can I repair it?

Comment: A [`::before` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) needs, at the very least, a `content: ""` property. What is the purpose of the pseudo element in your code? Why would you not set the animation on the `img` or the `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

```css
.back-to-top {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #c1c1c1;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
.back-to-top > i {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
}

.bounce {
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="back-to-top" role="button">
  <i class="arrow bounce"></i>
</a>
```